# How can I COMPLETELY disable snapping of vector shapes to the pixel grid in Photoshop CC2023?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, transform, snapping

I'm trying to understand if this is the correct behavior or if my preferences have been somehow corrupted.

I've disabled "Snap Vector Tools and Transforms to Pixel Grid" in the Preferences > Tools section:

[image]

I have snap completely disabled and extras hidden:

[image]

And yet despite all this ... vector shapes and even raster elements are snapping to the pixel grid when I am free transforming them. Sometimes elements snap to fractional coordinates too which is weird as well.

I've created a video of the behavior here:
https://streamable.com/aa5z1i

1. Can someone possibly confirm that this is the correct (intended) behavior?
2. Can someone supply a solution that disables this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I can only confirm that this is reproducable on my end as well. Also, I can confirm the following regarding the decimals when free transforming:

at 400% zoom, the decimals while free transforming increase and decrease in steps of .25 pixels using the arrow keys. At 500% the steps are made every .2 pixels, so you can imagine how this works for 300% zoom or any other zoom level as well. It stands to reason that these steps depend on zoom level, while optically always looking the same, on our screens, per keystroke; a pixel per arrow keystroke at 100% looks a lot different from moving the same amount but at 1200% zoom is what I am saying. And at 5344.56% (which is the zoom you used in your video explaining the issue), I can confirm the same behavior when free transforming, with parts of the object seemingly disappearing while moving in free transform, including very small decimal increments/decrements.

I believe that this is "working as intended", because after free transforming/moving an object to a desired spot on the canvas, we usually confirm this transformation, and Ps does the heavy lifting of approximating our input into actual and integer pixel values (which I personally believe to be simply rounding to closest pixel, as far as I can tell).